# CSS - Make a div "clickable"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know how i can render a div clickable (like a link, with the small hand when i go over with the mouse).

I have some elements like this:

```
<div class="teamSelector">Some</div>
```

With this jQuery:

```
$('.teamSelector').click(function() { 
    // some functions
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You've already made it clickable in your example. If you would like it to "look" clickable, you can add some CSS:

```
.teamSelector { cursor: pointer; }
```

Or continuing with jQuery:

```
.click(function() { do something }).css("cursor", "pointer");
```

[Here is](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) the W3 schools reference for the cursor property.

Comment: Yes. I've added a link to w3 schools in my post. It mentions browser support.

Comment: @markzzz You should add a tabindex attribute to any element that isn't a link or form element but that you choose to make clickable (btw, why?). To continue the above line of jQuery : `.css(...).attr('tabindex', 0);` Does your page work w/o JS?

Comment: Why? w/o=without? Sorry i don't understand :)

Answer (score 10):

The css for it is:

```
.teamSelector
{
  cursor: pointer
}
```

You can also add hover effects, but I'm not sure if :active will work cross-browser.

If you need something to be clickable, you're better off using a `button` or `a` element and styling that. You can always prevent the default action with javascript. The reason it's better is for accessibility so that users with screen readers know that there's something to interact with.

Edit to add:
When you tab through a page, you can hit the space bar to `click` an element. This will not work the same on non-interactive elements, so anyone using that functionality will not be able to use whatever it is you're making.

Comment: +1 and it's better not only for screen readers but for any disabled person using only a keyboard and no mouse. And links (plus button and input) are just made for that. The tabindex attribute will add an element to the list of tabbed ones but really links are made for that.

Answer (score 4):

this question is pretty old but needs some additions:

if you want to wrap component with pointer-based user interaction, you should prefer button element instead of a `div`(you can still display it `block`).

```
<button class="teamSelector" tabindex="1">Some</button>
```

styles:

```
.teamSelector{
    user-select: none; // this sets the element unselectable, unlike texts
    cursor: pointer; // changes the client's cursor
    touch-action: manipulation; // disables tap zoom delaying for acting like real button
    display: block; // if you want to display as block element
    background: transparent; //remove button style
    border: 0; //remove button style
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just, y'know, make it a link and style it? It would be easier and accessible.

Answer (score 3):

We can show div element clickable simply by adding style=cursor:'pointer'.
for example:

```
  <div style="cursor: pointer;">edit</div>
```

It will bring small hand when we go over div element with the mouse.

Comment: Definitely the most accessible answer